# Auto scroll up after clicking "new activity"

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Make the screen automatically scroll up to the top of the page after clicking "1 question with new activity" bar. Like, pull the screen back up to the first question with the new activities. This is convenient for people who's at the lower part of the page finding questions and wanting to go back to the top to view the new activities.